# Adding criteria for fractals to trade entry - Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Here is a picture of what I am aiming for:

[image]

I would like to test a simple strategy where one enters a trade if the Keltner channel is exceeded and then a fractal is generated.

The condition that I am trying to incorporate is in the last 4 lines of code:

```
if (topfractals)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100, when = Lower > close)

if (botfractals)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 100, when = Upper < close)
```

But it seems that the boolean I am looking for to identify a Fractal is not the 'topfractals'. Here is the complete code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("StrategyEx1", overlay=true)

/////////////////////////////////
// keltner channel
length = input(50, minval=1)
mult = input(5, "Multiplier")
src = input(close, title="Source")
exp = input(true, "Use Exponential MA")
BandsStyle = input("Average True Range")
//, options = ["Average True Range", "True Range", "Range"], title="Bands Style")
atrlength = input(1000, "ATR Length")
esma(source, length)=>
    s = sma(source, length)
    e = ema(source, length)
    exp ? e : s
ma = esma(src, length)
rangema = BandsStyle == "True Range" ? rma(tr(true), length) : BandsStyle == "Average True Range" ? atr(atrlength) : rma(high - low, length)
Upper = ma + rangema * mult
Lower = ma - rangema * mult
u = plot(Upper, color=#FF5252, title="Upper")
l = plot(Lower, color=#FF5252, title="Lower")

/////////////////////////////////
// Fractals 
hidefractals  = input(false)
//  ||---   Completed Fractals Recognition Functions:  -----------------------------------------------------||
isIdealFractal(mode) =>
    ret = mode == 1 ? high[4] < high[3] and high[3] < high[2] and high[2] > high[1] and high[1] > high[0] : 
          mode == -1 ? low[4] > low[3] and low[3] > low[2] and low[2] < low[1] and low[1] < low[0] : false
    
isRegularFractal(mode) =>
    ret = mode == 1 ? high[4] < high[2] and high[3] <= high[2] and high[2] > high[1] and high[2] > high[0] : 
          mode == -1 ? low[4] > low[2] and low[3] >= low[2] and low[2] < low[1] and low[2] < low[0] : false
          
topfractal = isRegularFractal(1)
botfractal = isRegularFractal(-1)

//Count How many candles for current Pivot Level, If new reset.
topcnt = 0
botcnt = 0
topcnt := topfractal ? 0 : nz(topcnt[1])+1
botcnt := botfractal ? 0 : nz(botcnt[1])+1

topfractals = 0.0
botfractals = 0.0
topfractals := topfractal ? high[2] : topfractals[1]
botfractals := botfractal ? low[2] : botfractals[1]

topfc = (topfractals != topfractals[1]) ? na : color.green
botfc = (botfractals != botfractals[1]) ? na : color.red

// === PLOTTING ===
plotshape(hidefractals ? na : topfractal, color=#4CAF50, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, size=size.auto)
plotshape(hidefractals ? na : botfractal, color=#FF5252, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, size=size.auto)

////////////////////////////////////
// Specify entry conditions

// Execute trade if condition is True
if (topfractals)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100, when = Lower > close)

if (botfractals)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 100, when = Upper < close)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if both conditions are true:

```
...
// === PLOTTING ===
plotshape(hidefractals ? na : topfractal and Lower > close, color=#4CAF50, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, size=size.auto)
plotshape(hidefractals ? na : botfractal and Upper < close, color=#FF5252, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, size=size.auto)
...
```

This can show is the strategy conditions are met on the chart.